# Error when filtering Dataframe (TypeError: invalid type comparison)

Tags: pandas

I am trying to filter out a Dataframe based on a column but I get an error `TypeError: invalid type comparison`

Given below is view of my Dataframe:

```
id,name,start_date,new_customer
101,customer_1,2018-12-01,True
102,customer_2,2018-11-21,False
103,customer_3,2018-12-11,True
104,customer_4,2018-11-30,False
```

I get the error when I try to do

```
df = df['new_customer']=='True'
```

Update

```
df.dtypes


id - object
name - object
start_date - datetime64[ns]
new_customer - bool
```

Comment: @ALollz, updated the dtypes. Yes the column is of type bool

Comment: How come bool values appear in capital letters? Am I missing something out here?

Comment: The error is that you are trying to compare the string `'TRUE'` with the boolean value `True`. Look at your `DataFrame` and you will see the values are not '`TRUE'` but were instead changed to `True`, since `pandas` decided it could safely typecast the column. You can prevent this if needed when you read in the data with `pd.read_csv`

Comment: @meW, sorry mis-typed it. I have updated values for the column now.

Comment: @darkhorse then it's easy. Just remove apostrophe. It's not a string datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `True` without apostrophe

```
df = df['new_customer'] == True
```